# Comscore SDK not tracking in Swift Project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, analytics, comscore

I have integrated ComScore SDK via Cocoapods `pod 'ComScore'` from [here](https://github.com/comscore/ComScore-iOS-watchOS-tvOS)

And added the `#import <ComScore/ComScore.h>` to my Briding header

And in my AppDelegate.swift

```
        let publisherConfiguration = SCORPublisherConfiguration(builderBlock: {(_ builder: SCORPublisherConfigurationBuilder) -> Void in
        builder.publisherId = "*******"
        builder.publisherSecret = "*******"
        builder.applicationName = "*******"
        } as? (SCORPublisherConfigurationBuilder?) -> Void)
    SCORAnalytics.configuration().addClient(with: publisherConfiguration)
    SCORAnalytics.start()
```

But is not sending my data to the server.

They have noted the below as the implementation in their objective c example app (they don have direct support for Swift , I integrated using BridgingHeader)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

SCORPublisherConfiguration *publisherConfiguration = [SCORPublisherConfiguration publisherConfigurationWithBuilderBlock:^(SCORPublisherConfigurationBuilder *builder) {
    builder.publisherId = @"1000001";
    builder.publisherSecret = @"9c455c81a801d3832a2cd281843dff30";
}];

[[SCORAnalytics configuration] addClientWithConfiguration:publisherConfiguration];
[SCORAnalytics start];

return YES;
}
```

Comment: what is this `as? (SCORPublisherConfigurationBuilder?) -> Void)`

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    
    SCORPublisherConfiguration *publisherConfiguration = [SCORPublisherConfiguration publisherConfigurationWithBuilderBlock:^(SCORPublisherConfigurationBuilder *builder) {
        builder.publisherId = @"1000001";
        builder.publisherSecret = @"9c455c81a801d3832a2cd281843dff30";
    }];
    
    [[SCORAnalytics configuration] addClientWithConfiguration:publisherConfiguration];
    [SCORAnalytics start];

    return YES;
}

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This is the objective c implementation they gave in their example project

Comment: now problem is solved or not

Comment: no bro have a look at this question now its updated.

Comment: problem is still there?

Comment: with out this  builder.applicationName = "*******" try once

Comment: tried again its not working :(

Comment: ok apply the these id builder.publisherId = @"1000001";
    builder.publisherSecret = @"9c455c81a801d3832a2cd281843dff30"; in your app and check once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct syntax is

```
    let check = SCORPublisherConfiguration(builderBlock: {(_ builder : SCORPublisherConfigurationBuilder!) -> Void in
        builder.publisherId = "1000001"
        builder.publisherSecret = "9c455c81a801d3832a2cd281843dff30"
        builder.applicationName = "karthik_Test"

    } )
    SCORAnalytics.configuration().addClient(with: check)
    SCORAnalytics.start()
```

and **ComScore framework** needs the **AdSupport framework** dont forget to add.